# $E(|X+Y|^p)\ge E(|X|^p)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $E(|X|^p)<\infty$ for some $p\ge 1$, and $E(Y) = 0$, then $E(|X+Y|^p)\ge E(|X|^p)$.

Is it maybe true that for each fixed $x$ that the following inequality is true?
$$\int|x+y|^p \mu_Y(dy) \ge |x|^p$$

So that integrating both sides would give

$$\int\int|x+y|^p \mu_Y(dy)\mu_X(dx) \ge \int|x|^p\mu_X(dx)$$

Comment: Have you tried Jensen's inequality?

Comment: @Tim: Jensen's inequality with which function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $E(Y)=0$ you can rewrite your first display equation as $$E(|x+Y|^p)\geq |x+E(Y)|^p$$

For $p\geq 1$ the function $f(y) = |x+y|^p$ is convex, hence the result follows from Jensen's inequality.